# Grafana deploy in kubernetes with Letsencript certificate in ingess

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, grafana, helm

I want to deploy grafana in my AKS kubernetes cluster. For deployment I use helm

```
helm install grafana grafana/grafana --namespace=grafana --set "service.type=ClusterIP,persistence.enabled=true,replicaCount=1,persistence.size=10Gi,persistence.accessModes[0]=ReadWriteOnce,plugins=grafana-azure-monitor-datasource\,grafana-kubernetes-app,ingress.enabled=true,ingress.tls[0]=enabeld,ingress.tls[0].hosts[0]=mydomain.de,ingress.tls[0].secretName=tls-grafana-ingress,ingress.hosts[0]=mydomain.de,ingress.annotations.kubernetes.io/ingress.class=nginx,ingress.cert-manager.io/issuer=letsencrypt-prod"
```

It can create grafana (when I remove "`ingress.annotations.kubernetes.io/ingress.class=nginx,ingress.cert-manager.io/issuer=letsencrypt-prod`") but I have problems with the tls certificate.
The certificate will not cerate.

What I need to change, so the certifiacate will also create?

Regards
Stefan

Comment: What are the errors you received?

Comment: When I canched the it to 

--set ingress.annotations."kubernetes\.io/ingress\.class"=nginx  
--set ingress."cert-manager\.io/cluster-issuer"=letsencrypt-prod

Then there will be no errors the tls certificate will not cerateted.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes and helm did you use?

Comment: Helm version 3.6.2   / Kubernetes 1.19.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

First I create the certificate and secound I add the certificate to the ingress rule.